# Error: build and install Containernet (Mininet) on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, docker

I wanted to install containernet (Mininet) on Ubuntu 20.4 I got this error although I already installed (cgroup-tools)
the command I typed
`sudo ansible-playbook -i "localhost," -c local install.yml`
the error message

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd":
 "containernet/util/install.sh", "delta": "0:00:05.640086", "end": "2020-09-01 16:09:32.350865", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 100, 
"start": "2020-09-01 16:09:26.710779", "stderr": "E: Package 'cgroup-bin' 
has no installation candidate", "stderr_lines": ["E: Package 'cgroup-bin' 
has no installation candidate"], "stdout": "Detected Linux distribution: 
Ubuntu 20.04 focal amd64\npython3 is version 3\nInstalling all packages 
except for -eix (doxypy, ivs, nox-classic)...\nInstall Mininet-compatible 
kernel if necessary\nHit:1 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal 
InRelease\nHit:2 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal 
InRelease\nHit:3 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates 
InRelease\nHit:4 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports 
InRelease\nHit:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security 
InRelease\nReading package lists...\nReading package lists...\nBuilding 
dependency tree...\nReading state information...\nlinux-image-5.4.0-42-
generic is already the newest version (5.4.0-42.46).\nThe following package 
was automatically installed and is no longer required:\n  libfprint-
2-tod1\nUse 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.\n0 to upgrade, 0 to newly 
install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.\nInstalling Mininet 
dependencies\nReading package lists...\nBuilding dependency tree...\nReading 
state information...\nPackage cgroup-bin is not available, but is referred 
to by another package.\nThis may mean that the package is missing, has been 
obsoleted, or\nis only available from another source\nHowever the following 
packages replace it:\n  cgroup-tools", "stdout_lines": ["Detected Linux 
distribution: Ubuntu 20.04 focal amd64", "python3 is version 3", "Installing 
all packages except for -eix (doxypy, ivs, nox-classic)...", "Install 
Mininet-compatible kernel if necessary", "Hit:1 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com
/ubuntu focal InRelease", "Hit:2 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu 
focal InRelease", "Hit:3 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates 
InRelease", "Hit:4 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports 
InRelease", "Hit:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security 
InRelease", "Reading package lists...", "Reading package lists...", 
"Building dependency tree...", "Reading state information...", "linux-image-
5.4.0-42-generic is already the newest version (5.4.0-42.46).", "The 
following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:", "  
libfprint-2-tod1", "Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.", "0 to upgrade, 
0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.", "Installing Mininet 
dependencies", "Reading package lists...", "Building dependency tree...", 
"Reading state information...", "Package cgroup-bin is not available, but is 
referred to by another package.", "This may mean that the package is 
missing, has been obsoleted, or", "is only available from another source", 
"However the following packages replace it:", "  cgroup-tools"]}
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was also facing a similar issue. I think the ansible for containernet is using cgi-bin which is deprecated on its own, its only accessible by cgroup-tools. Its a problem with 20.04.

I would recommend you to work on the docker image as it runs on ubuntu trusty and docker containers are easy to manage.

Answer (score 0):

Download the proper version from: https://pkgs.org/download/cgroup-bin

install it via `sudo dpkg -i cgroup-bin_*.deb`